# Is there Any Alternative for Switch Case Statements in Java ? Any Good Design Pattern ? My Switch case Statement Increasing How to Avoid

Tags: java, switch-statement

Below Code, I wrote to execute the switch-case statement, for each condition.
Now I am thinking to remove the switch-case statement and apply some design pattern to overcome this issue.
// main iteration - for every sheet
            for (Entry>> entry : testCaseSheetsDataMap.entrySet()) {

```
            String sheetNameKey = entry.getKey().trim();
            String testCaseName = testCaseSheetMasterMap.get(sheetNameKey).trim();
            List<Map<String, Object>> executableRowsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
            executableRowsList = entry.getValue();

            CitiMainAuxiliary auxiliary = new CitiMainAuxiliary();

            switch (testCaseName) {

            case "Anonymous Mode Log In":
                auxiliary.runAllLogin(executableRowsList, testCaseName, Constants.ANONYMOUS);
                break;
            case "Login Mode":
                auxiliary.runAllLogin(executableRowsList, testCaseName, Constants.LOGIN);
                break;
            case "Cookied Mode Login":
                auxiliary.runAllLogin(executableRowsList, testCaseName, Constants.COOKIED);
                break;
            case "OBO Mode Login":
                auxiliary.runAllLogin(executableRowsList, testCaseName, Constants.OBO);
                break;

            case "Anonymous Mode Megamenu":
                auxiliary.runMegaMenu(executableRowsList, testCaseName, Constants.ANONYMOUS);
                break;
            case "Login Mode Megamenu":
                auxiliary.runMegaMenu(executableRowsList, testCaseName, Constants.LOGIN);
                break;
            case "Cookied Mode Logon - Megamenu Check":
                auxiliary.runMegaMenu(executableRowsList, testCaseName, Constants.COOKIED);
                break;
            case "OBO Logon - Megamenu Check":
                auxiliary.runMegaMenu(executableRowsList, testCaseName, Constants.OBO);
                break;

            }

        } // end-for testCaseSheetsDataMap
```

Comment: You're looking for Replace Conditional with Polymorphism.

Comment: Why you want to replace `switch`? What problems do you have with it?

Comment: I am reading data from Excel and sometimes my case statement gets modified in Excel my switch case won't work. Because of that  want to replace

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can write a `HashMap<string,Constants>` and run something like:

```
auxiliary.runMegaMenu(executableRowsList, testCaseName, map.get("Login Mode Megamenu"));
```

and additionally you could introduce a `HashSet<string>()` where you store all strings for the `runMegaMenu`-methods and than you could check it the following way:

```
if(set.contains(testCaseName)){
   auxiliary.runMegaMenu(executableRowsList, testCaseName, map.get(testCaseName));
}else{
   auxiliary.runAllLogin(executableRowsList, testCaseName, map.get(testCaseName));
}
```

But back to your question. Switch-case can generally be avoided by **polymorphism** I personally prefer the **Strategy-Pattern** for cases like your example.

Answer (score 0):

As was mention you can use `polymorphism` and `Strategy` pattern.

For example you can create `Map<String, BiConsumer<CitiMainAuxiliary, List<Map<String, Object>>> strategies` and populate it

```
strategies.put("Anonymous Mode Log In", (aux, list)-> aux.runAllLogin(list,...))
```

After that instead of switch statement you can use 
`strategy = strategies.get(testCaseName);
strategy.accept(...)`

If you can't use Java 8 you can create an Interface and use `Map<String, YourInterface>` instead of map of BiConsumer. Maybe the implementation with interfaces is better, because in every particular class you can initialize your Constants, like `COOKIED` or `OBO`